# AVAudioPlayer iPhone question

Tags: iphone, cocoa, avaudioplayer, microphone

With the AVAudioPlayer, can I stream live audio from my microphone?

If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AudioQueues you'll always have a slight delay when filling up the buffer, AudioUnits would be the way to go as you can work with sound instantly.

Comment: And take a look at : http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SimplePlayThru/listing2.html

Answer (score 1):

No.

AVAudioPlayer only can play audio files.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to look into AudioQueues and the [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/aurioTouch/index.html) example from Apple's sample code

Comment: For example, it would be like a mega phone.

Right when I would speak into the mic, it should come out the speaker. Would i use AudioQueues for that?

Answer (score 1):

Just as pjapers said. You should use AudioUnits